# Image not getting rendered

Tags: php, html, http, jpgraph

```
<img alt="image" src="genImage.php" />
```

In the genImage.php im basically stoking the graph using JPgraph. It works fine on localhost but on the server its not working. What could be the reason and is there any solution to this problem.

P.S. I'm getting HTTP 500 server error for the above problem.

Comment: Is that a thing? Linking a page through `<img>`? If so I did not know that.

Comment: If you actually have the same files on localhost and the server, then it sounds like the server is not configured properly. Did you check your server's log files? Might be anything without more info.

Comment: when the src is a php the page will do a http request to fetch the page which in this case is a image.

Comment: there was some lib incompatibility of libPNG version on the server. I changed image type to jpeg and it worked fine